# Store String and Int in an Array as input in Java

Tags: java, tcp, client-server

I am trying to develop a simple client-server application to send a command to the server, process it, then send the result back and display it.

The user will be asked to enter a request in the form of "command x y".

For example, the user will enter: `add 5 10` 
The output will then be `The add result is: 30`

The application can accept the following as command: add, subtract, multiply, divide

As the user is expected to input the request in one line, I am thinking of storing the user input in an array and use a switch-case such that if the first command is add, it will add the x and y. If the first command is substract, it will minus the x and y...

However, in the user request, there is a combination of string (the command) and integers (x and y). I am unsure how to do this. Also, is my approach efficient?

I already figured out the connection set up for client and server.

Comment: Post the code you've developed?

Comment: Convert the strings to integers as needed?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `Scanner` and parse the line with the user input using Scanner's `next`, `nextInt` methods:

```java
String userInput = "add 5 10";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(userInput);
String cmd = scan.next();
int arg1 = scan.nextInt();
int arg2 = scan.nextInt();

int res = switch (cmd) {
    case "add" -> arg1 + arg2;
    case "subtract" -> arg1 - arg2;
    default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported command: " + cmd);
};
```